# Move to record and not filter to record

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Currently my dropdownlist returns a value that I use in a SQL WHERE clause to return a result set.  I would like to be able to just move to the selected record as oppose to filtering the whole set.  When I filter I am no longer able to page through the records (I can only choose another search selection from the dropdownlist because there are no other records to page through - I would like to use both).  What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you post your code what you did so far?

Comment: I do not use any any code behind for this page.  I have a sql datasource (1) that populates the DDL and a sql datasource (2)  that populates the data using the variable from the DDL in a WHERE clause.

Comment: Ok. Understood. May be you can use custom pagination to achieve your paging. And actual result will be displayed in grid. Let me now if you understand.

Comment: @Piyush Khatri Thank you for your help.  Not quite sure exactly what you mean by custom pagination - I am using the pager that is built in but it does not appear when I select a record from DDL.  The selected record appears from SQL query and the pagination disappears (I presume because only the selected item is in the current recordset).

Comment: Let me explain you. Suppose there are 100 rows. So first create custom pagination. It means lets say page size 10, so you should have links like 1,2,...10. Now for grid bind actual result. It means if you get only 5 records of page. Just bind those only.

Comment: Thank you again for your help, but that does seem to be what I am looking for.  I would like to be able to select one item from the DropDownList and/or    page all records.  Note: in my case, only one record would be displayed at any given time.

Comment: Lets discuss in chat if you are still unclear with what I suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105908/discussion-between-user2796515-and-piyush-khatri).